# wordpress theme doesn't appear

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm having a very basic problem: I'm trying to create a new theme for a wordpress installation locally on my computer.

I've created a styles.css and index.php file and put it in a folder in wp-content/themes. But it doesn't appear in the Wordpress themes page.

As a test, I made a change to the description of one of the existing themes (Twenty-Ten) in its style.css, and refresh the Wordpress themes page, but the old description continues to be shown. This suggests to me that I'm simply using the wrong folder, but that's not possible! Any ideas on this problem much appreciated.

UPDATE: In fact, even when I delete Twenty Ten from the Themes folder, it's still available as an option in the Wordpress backend, and I can activate it... Very strange...

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your diagnosis. You are either looking at the wrong folder or in fact the wrong computer.  There's no other way that you could change the theme to one that has been deleted.

I suggest that you confirm you are in the same universe you think you are in.  Create a simple file localserver.txt in your WordPress directory and then confirm that you can access that file.

If you can't, you have your answer. You are somehow accessing a different location.

If you can access that text file, you need to go further and look to see if something like the site url setting is redirecting you to the live site, without you realizing it, when you access wp-admin.

Beyond that, I'd need to know more about your setup.  Something like having www.example.com in your /etc/host file and not example.com can cause similar confusion...

Comment: Yes, thank you. That simple text file test confirmed it was pointing to the wrong place. I have two xampp set ups, on different hard drives, and I was using the wrong one. Very stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Wordpress Multisite?
In that case you have to 'enable' that theme in the Network admin manager

Comment: Your answer does not fit what he stated in his question.  He said he edited the title of an existing theme and it did not change in WP. He also stated he deleted an existing theme and still could see it.  That  does not indicate that his new theme was simply not enabled for a multisite site. It indicates he is working in a different WP directory from the one he is visiting in the browser. Which he indeed said was the case on the same day I answered his question, over a month before you supplied a second answer and down voted the one that identified his issue and helped him resolve his problem.